# Read-level Auditing in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We have a (challenging!!) requirement to audit read-operations in CRM. This audit won't be the OOTB CRM Auditing but audit to an external auditing system via web services. Basically we will be classifying all the entity fields as High/Medium/Low and whenever any user views any fields tagged as High/Medium, we need to audit it.

I understand that Read-level auditing isn't supported OOTB by CRM and this requirement will have significant performance impact, however there is no way out since this is a business-critical functionality. Since the CRM records can be viewed from multiple sources (Form, Home Grid, Sub Grid, Advanced Find, Lookup Views, etc.), I am trying to look for a common solution that works in all the scenarios. One approach I tried out is using plugins on Retrieve/RetrieveMultiple messages and have the custom audit logic in the plugin, however I am concerned about the performance impact this approach will have. Another approach I can think of would be to handle this using Javascript, however the Javascript approach won't work with 
all the scenarios like Advanced Find, Lookup Views, etc.

**I am looking for suggestions on any other better solution to this.**

Comment: you are talking about both fetching records & viewing record in form. so first approach is the only choice.

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch your plugins to Async mode. This should not cause such huge performance impact as Sync plugin cause.
I'm afraid that Plugins is the only solution for you. Good luck implementing it.

Comment: I agree that plugins are the way to go. I have yet to integrate a plugin to the Azure Service Bus, but that might help with storage and performance concerns. For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334766.aspx